# Different direct product in a category and its full subcategory

Tags: category-theory, products

A question related to [Continuing direct product on a subcategory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/446877/continuing-direct-product-on-a-subcategory).

Let $F$ is a full subcategory of a category $G$.

I denote $\operatorname{Ob}X$ the set of objects of a category $X$.

Is it possible the following?

- There are binary direct products $\times_F$ and $\times_G$ in these categories.
- $A\times_G B\in\operatorname{Ob}F$ if $A, B\in\operatorname{Ob}F$.
- $A\times_G B$ is non-isomorphic to $A\times_F B$ for some objects $A$, $B$ of $F$.

We probably should also assume that the product morphisms are the same for $F$ and $G$ (provided that the morphisms are morphisms of $F$).

Comment: Does it remain impossible, if we require it only for two fixed objects $A$ and $B$ of $F$ rather than for all $A,B\in\operatorname{Ob}F$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Under the given hypotheses, $A \times_G B \cong A \times_F B$ naturally. To see this it suffices to observe that they represent the same functor when restricted to $F$.

Comment: "represent the same functor"? What does it mean? I am not (yet) a category theory expert

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representable_functor and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoneda_lemma . By definition, the product of two objects $A, B$ in a category is a representing object of the functor $\text{Hom}(-, A) \times \text{Hom}(-, B)$.